# Get absolute path from relative path?

Tags: python, path

I have two inputs:

```
filepath = '/var/folders/T/tmptwvailgg/x11-dl/src/xss.rs'
relpath = '../../src/xss.rs'
```

From these two inputs, I want the absolute path of the target file. In the above example, the output would be:

```
target_path = '/var/folders/T/tmptwvailgg/src/xss.rs'
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: What have you done to try and find the answer yourself?

Comment: Well,  I've been looking at the functions in `os.path`, but haven't figured out a solution. `os.path.realpath` and `os.path.abspath` depend on the current working directory of the python program, and does not give me the correct answer.

Comment: Did you try just joining the relative part to the absolute part?

Comment: `os.path.join`? Yes, it gives `/var/folders/T/tmptwvailgg/x11-dl/src/xss.rs/../../srs/xss/rs'

Comment: ok got it,, I'd also have to use `os.path.realpath` after the join. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.join(filepath, relpath))
```